# Null pointer exception on getter setter in java

Tags: java, android, getter-setter

I have a getter setter class named SharedData.java . I am getting null pointer exception when I'm going to imply it on my code . Here is the SharedData class :

```
public class SharedData {
private static SharedData instance = null;

public SharedData() {
    // randomizeServers();
}

// data to be shared
private double src_latitude = -1;
private double src_longitude = -1;
private double end_latitude = -1;
private double end_longitude = -1;

//Getter-Setters
public static SharedData getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
public static void setInstance(SharedData instance) {
    SharedData.instance = instance;
}

public double getSrc_latitude() {
    return src_latitude;
}
public void setSrc_latitude(double src_latitude) {
    this.src_latitude = src_latitude;
}
public double getSrc_longitude() {
    return src_longitude;
}
public void setSrc_longitude(double src_longitude) {
    this.src_longitude = src_longitude;
}
public double getEnd_latitude() {
    return end_latitude;
}
public void setEnd_latitude(double end_latitude) {
    this.end_latitude = end_latitude;
}
public double getEnd_longitude() {
    return end_longitude;
}
public void setEnd_longitude(double end_longitude) {
    this.end_longitude = end_longitude;
}

}
```

Here is  my code :

```
       SharedData sharedData ;  
       sharedData = SharedData.getInstance();
       sharedData.setSrc_latitude(latitude);
   sharedData.setEnd_longitude(longitude);
```

Can anybody please help me with this ? Thanks .

Comment: *"I am getting null pointer exception"* => read the stack trace, find the corresponding line in your code, find what's wrong on that line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never initialized `sharedData`, so its value is `null`, calling a method on it got your program to crash.

I think you're trying to use `Singleton Pattern`. Try the below:

```
private static SharedData instance = new SharedData();   \\ Initialize here

private SharedData() {        // Make it private....
    // randomizeServers();
}

// data to be shared
private double src_latitude = -1;
private double src_longitude = -1;
private double end_latitude = -1;
private double end_longitude = -1;

//Getter-Setters
public static SharedData getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: I would be ever thankful to the person who just downvoted my question, even after this being the correct one......

Comment: after doing this , when I am trying to initiate sharedData it gives the following error : 
The Constructor SharedData() is not visible .

Comment: opps sorry ! it worked . I inilized it again in my code mistakenly . Thanks a lot . :-)

Comment: @FahimAhmed You are welcome............ But just a request.... try to understand and execute the code snippet before you jump onto a sudden conclusion...that has helped me...and i am sure will help every other person who reacts to situations, rather than responding...... thanks once again

Answer (score 3):

```
SharedData.getInstance();
```

Returns `null`. Later you're trying to call a method on it:

```
sharedData.setSrc_latitude(latitude);
```

Which is illegal as reference to object is still `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't instanciate the class, so `getInstance()` returns `null`.

At the start of your class, replace :

```
private static SharedData instance = null;
```

by :

```
private static SharedData instance =  new SharedData() ; // creates a new instance
```

Comment: sharedData.setSrc_latitude(latitude);

Answer (score 1):

Even using the `singleton pattern` you should instantiate the object `SharedData` at least once.

try this

```
SharedData sharedData = new SharedData();  
       sharedData = SharedData.getInstance();
       sharedData.setSrc_latitude(latitude);
   sharedData.setEnd_longitude(longitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

change `private static SharedData instance = null;`

to `private static SharedData instance = this;`

and make your class static

`public static class SharedData {`

Also , make the getters setters static..

Comment: haha, is it? or do you mean just a 'bad answer'? i think so too. i have never worked with c#, btw.